# The Number Of Points Isnt Changing... Please Fix

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

Im Trying To Make A Rapid Fire Type Question, Basically "j" is the variable for points and i want it to change/decrease (and to check for messages) every 0.5 seconds ... The Problem Is That No Matter How Late I Try I get 1000 points. Also Im New. (btw sorry for bad english)

The Code:

```
    def check(m):
        return m.author == message.author and m.channel
    mn = randint(5, 15)
    mn1 = randint(5, 10)
    mz = mn * mn1
    membed = discord.Embed(
        title="Here's The Question", 
        description=str(mn) + " * " + str(mn1) + ''' Type Your Answer Below.. ''',
        url=None,
        color=discord.Color.blue())
    mzz = await message.send(embed=membed)
    j = 1100
    for i in range(0, 5):
        sleep(0.5)
        j = j - 100
        gt = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if int(gt.content) == int(mz):
            await message.send(f'Its Right.. You Got **{j}** Points')
        else:
            await message.send(f'Its Wrong.. The Answer Is **{j}**')
```

Please Help...

Comment: This isn't enough to help debug. What is `message`? When you say "the number of points isn't changing", are you seeing that variable `j` is not being modified, or something else?

Comment: i want j to decrease every 0.5 seconds and also i want it to check for messages every 0.5 seconds... the problem is that no matter how late i type im getting 1000 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're misunderstanding how `await` works.

`await foo()` causes your program to sleep *until* `foo()` returns a value.

When you type `await bot.wait_for()`, you are saying:

1. Sleep until `bot.wait_for()` returns a value
2. `bot.wait_for()` only returns a value *when* it receives a message.

The full flow of your program is thus:

1. You enter the first loop `i = 0`. `j` gets set to 1000.
2. You sleep until you receive a message. Because you can receive a message any time in the future (say, ten seconds or ten minutes or fifteen hours, etc.), you never enter the second loop `i = 1`. Basically, your program is frozen at this point until somebody sends you a message.

The solution here is to ask your bot to *time out* waiting for a message, so it can continue to the next value of `i`. A timeout tells your bot to sleep only for a specified amount of time before continuing your program. Conveniently, the `wait_for` command provides a [`timeout`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) parameter:

```
j = 1100
for i in range(0, 5):
    j = j - 100
    try: # A try/except block is needed because this throws an error if bot times out
        gt = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=0.5)
        if int(gt.content) == int(mz):
            await message.send(f'Its Right.. You Got **{j}** Points')
            break
        else:
            await message.send(f'Its Wrong.. The Answer Is **{j}**')
    except:
        continue
else:
    await message.send("Whoops, you're out of time! You got zero points.")
```

Comment: even though i wrote the answer it sends the timeout message

Comment: Updated. I've used a little-known Python feature called `for/else` loops.

Comment: it still shows the timeout message even though I wrote the right answer , is there an error??

Comment: nevermind I forgot the break command ... sorry

Comment: If this answer worked for you, kindly upvote and mark as correct.